# How to test my cordova app with paypal cordova plugin

Tags: paypal, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I had refered the cordova plugin https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin . But how to create test accounts for buyer and seller. I referred the link but I couldnt get proper idea.
Please help me by providing steps how to test my app. 
Otherwise, How to use this plugin with help of inappbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

After referring the documentation on PayPal. I got an idea on the implementation and the way to test the sample app.

1. Login to PayPal https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
2. Go to Accounts tab under Sandbox.
3. Here click on create account and create sample business and personal account.
4. Then navigate to My Apps & Credentials section.Click on create app buttton. Enter the app name and give the sandbox developer account.
5. Once after app is created, u can find sandbox and live switch button on top left of the app page
6. Specify the required sandbox settings.
7. Follow the steps for building hybrid app with cordova paypal integration using https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin
8. Specify the production and sandbox client id in the configuration.
9. Build and run the app.
10. On click of Pay using paypal with show the login page. Login with your paypal account.
11. The amount will be paid to the account that is specified in sandbox.
12. Verify the payment by checking the account details.
    Go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ . Click on the business account created in sandbox. Check the notifications. You can find the transactions that you have made.

This is how we can test sample paypal app. This is what I have referred to test  the sample app. But there is so much to dig into the topic.

Thanks